# Campo texto as400 se ven como varbinary en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, conversión-de-tipos, as400

Tengo un Servidor AS400 (IBM i) por Linked Server a SQL, el problema radica en que algunos valores  (tipo  texto (varchar)) no se Visualizan correctamente, se ve algo como esto en el resultado de la consulta por OpenQuery

```
   0xD4C5C4C9C1404040404040404040404040404040
```

Existe alguna forma de convertir este resultado al texto Normal, he intentado de la siguiente forma pero no obtengo el resultado esperado

```
declare @b varbinary(max)
set @b = 0xE3C5D4D7D9C1D5C1404040404040404040
select cast(@b as varchar(max))
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Me parece que en vez de tratar de convertir el valor de vuelta a texto, sería bueno entender porque no lo recibes de la forma adecuada en primer lugar. Tal vez se te pueda brindar ayuda en ese sentido, pero casi no das detalles en cuenta al problema en sí.

Comment: Creo que lo que estas obteniendo es un apuntador al valor, o es un valor cifrado. No recuerdo muy bien

Comment: He leído acerca del problema presentado al parecer por la codificación (code page)  que maneja el SO donde se encuentra La base de IBM es diferente a donde estoy ejecutando el Query que es un Sistema Windows. Parece ser que en la configuración del Linked Server toca establecer una propiedad que permita la interpretación correcta de estos datos, de momento pensaba en un solución sin tener que intervenir la conexión ya que no tengo acceso a esa configuración, pero de ser así como poder realizarlo para solicitarlo al administrador. @sstan

Comment: Las plataformas IBM se manejan  generalmente con el formato EBCDIC, tu ejemplo me hace suponer que efectivamente es así, los varios 0x40 son espacios en esta codificación. Revisa como dice sstan la configuración del linked server.

Comment: Te confirmo los datos que estás recibiendo son en EBCDIC, traduciendo los dos ejemplos que diste: `0xD4C5C4C9C1404040404040404040404040404040  = MEDIA` y `0xE3C5D4D7D9C1D5C1404040404040404040 = TEMPRANA`